# Application of mutable database structures?

Tags: database

I'm wondering if there are any benefits one could gain by taking advantage of the possibility to alter the database's table structures on the fly and querying the DB engine for the current structure before making queries (or just using the fields that are sure to be in the table). Are there any examples of systems that use such approach?

Comment: Well, [tag:mongodb] (document-oriented NoSQL database) might be considered as an example, where each record might have different properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://blog.mongodb.org/post/119945109/why-schemaless.

From my personal experience I've found the following benefits:

**Easier to change**

Some conceptual structures are just too much of a pain to use in a normalized set of tables. For example, at my job we have a custom internal CMS system. To represent one "article" we have around 35 tables. When we have to run queries to generate one full article it is very painful.

When that same article is represented as a document, all the information is still there, it's just considerably easier to change the object in code and then serialize and de-serialize instead of writing queries with 20 joins.

**Versioning**

It makes versioning so much easier. You might start with one schema for your system and later decide you need to add/remove fields. In a traditional RDBMS this can be painful to deploy.  With a document database, you just insert new documents with a different schema and everything is fine. (Keep in mind document data stores give you tools to handle this!)

**Faster Development**

This flows out of things being easier to change. The gain is *significant* from what I've seen. No more spending time making tables and making sure the data types are perfect and everything is very normalized.